# How to bind collection of colors in listbox (mvvm)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, colors

i am trying to get all the colors and fill my listbox with the list of  colors in mvvm.For that i am using below code but it gives error in below code.Please let me know where i am wrong.

**Property**

```
 private List<Color> _colorlist;
 public List<Color> ColorList
 {
     get { return _colorlist; }
     set
     {
         _colorlist = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged(() => _colorlist);
     }
 }
```

---

```
  List<Color> list = new List<Color>();
  Type colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
  if (null != colorType)
  {
       PropertyInfo[] propInfoList =
       colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
                        | BindingFlags.Public);
       int nNumProps = propInfoList.Length;
       for (int i = 0; i < nNumProps; i++)
       {
            PropertyInfo propInfo = (PropertyInfo)propInfoList[i];
            object[] index = null;
            list.Add((Color)propInfo.GetValue(null, index)); //Specified cast is not valid.

             string strColorName = propInfo.Name;
       }
   }
```

Comment: -1 for presenting a very poor quality question. Try *using words* to describe your problem, don't just throw your code at us... *it gives error in below code* is *not* a useful description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see at least two problems in your code:

- In the property setter, you're using `RaisePropertyChanged(() => _colorlist)` to raise the notification. It should be `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Colorlist)`, because you're binding to `ColorList`, not to `_colorlist` (which is private). That's not what is causing the problem, but it means that the binding system won't detect when the property value changes.
- you're getting the colors from `System.Drawing.Color` (which is the GDI+ color type), and you're casting the values to `Color`, which I assume is `System.Windows.Media.Color`, i.e. the WPF color type. Even though they have the same name, they're not the same type, hence the invalid cast exception. You should get the colors from the properties of the `System.Windows.Media.Colors` class instead.